# How to choose Elastic IP when my aws lambda function execute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, elastic-ip

I want to select specific Elastic IP my own when my lambda function executed.

my service has to respond to several situations, and by user's attributes. 
Could I write code in a lambda function, that can choose specific my own elastic IP?

I had searched for this. but old information says it cannot do.
but recently I heard about it is possible by using Network Load Balancer or Application Load Balancer.
But I don't know how to use this for the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "choose"? Give an example

Comment: _Why_ do you wish to do this? Most use-cases for people wanting to use multiple public IP addresses is to perform scraping against websites that block too much traffic coming from a given IP address. We do not support or encourage violating a web site's terms and conditions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No. You cannot associate an Elastic IP (EIP) address with an AWS Lambda function.

Well, actually you can, but I wouldn't recommend it. When a Lambda function is associated with a VPC, it connects via an Elastic Network Interface (ENI). It *is* possible to attach an EIP to an ENI. This also grants access to the Internet if it is attached to a public subnet.

So why avoid it? Because Lambda might create additional ENIs, especially if the Lambda function is frequently invoked and run in parallel. This means it will not have a consistent ENI.

An alternative method is:

- Attach the AWS Lambda function to a private subnet
- Put a **NAT Gateway** in a public subnet
- Associate an Elastic IP address with the NAT Gateway
- All traffic from the Lambda function to the Internet will then come from the NAT Gateway's EIP (however, I don't think you can change that EIP)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the free solution? Attaching Elastic IP to Lambda function without using NAT Gateway or NAT instance

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question:
how do I create a lambda stack that can grab some data from an endpoint on the internet, parse it, and load it into an RDS in a private-isolated subnet inside my VPC on AWS.

I ended up going with 2 lambda functions (one on private subnet, and the other not connected to my VPC), and communicating the parsed data between the two lambdas using an SNS/SQS, because I can open an endpoint on the private-subnet for the SNS/SQS messages to pass through.

I found this answer to be more complete:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74683282

Answer (score -1):

Looking at @John Rotenstein's reply: for small systems, with limited calls to the same lambda adding an EIP to the ENI for a lambda could work - if you put a queue in front of the lambda to handle the requests and limit the concurrency of the lambda to 1. That's cheaper than a NAT Gateway (saves around $30) per month. For larger systems, this may not be an issue and you may need the concurrency to be more than one - in that case the NAT gateway is the only way out.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the free solution? Attaching Elastic IP to Lambda function without using NAT Gateway or NAT instance