# Lambda function times out when connecting to a boto3 client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

### The Problem

I am trying to set up a lambda function to do some tasks on ec2. I keep running into a timeout error. A minimal example reproducing the problem is as follows:

```
import boto3

REGION = "us-west-2"
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION)


def main(event, context):
    
    region = ec2.describe_regions()
    return region
```

The lambda function is called `lambda_function` and the handler is `lambda_function.main`. The runtime environment is Python 3.6, Python 3.7 or Python 3.8 (and I have the same error in each).

This function returns the following error:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "2020-11-27T05:26:27.739Z xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx Task timed out after 20.02 seconds"
}

Request ID:
"xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"

Function logs:
START RequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
REPORT RequestId: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx  Duration: 20020.38 ms   Billed Duration: 20000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 81 MB  Init Duration: 343.37 ms    
2020-11-27T05:26:27.739Z xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx Task timed out after 20.02 seconds
```

### Permissions and Policies

The lambda function is running with a role with the following permissions:

- AmazonEC2FullAccess
- AWSLambdaFullAccess
- CloudWatchLogsFullAccess

The user that is setting up the lambda function has the following permissions:

- AmazonRDSFullAccess
- AmazonEC2FullAccess
- SecretsManagerReadWrite
- AWSLambdaFullAccess
- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
- AWSLambda_FullAccess
- EC2InstanceConnect

If I run the commands from my terminal, using the same credentials that this IAM user has, I get the expected output.

```
$ aws ec2 describe-regions
{
    "Regions": [
        {
            "Endpoint": "ec2.eu-north-1.amazonaws.com",
            "RegionName": "eu-north-1",
            "OptInStatus": "opt-in-not-required"
        },

    ...]
}
```

### Network and security groups

The lambda is assigned to the default VPC of the IAM user. The security groups attached to this lambda function are the default security group for this VPC, and some additional security groups allowing some additional access.

What is causing the timeout? How do I fix this?

Comment: You can confirm the Lambda function have access to the internet?

Comment: Inbound access at ports 80, 443 and 22, and outbound access on all ports. Unless I am misunderstanding your question...?

Comment: I guess you did not configure any NAT instance ... right?

Comment: I did not configure any NAT instance

Comment: I see.. Try to look at some resources I added and see if It is the reason for your issues. I tested your function code in a public Lambda and it works fine. So I think i got your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is most likely that your function does not have internet access for a workload that require connecting to internet endpoints

By default, Lambda inside VPCs [will not have access to the Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992085/why-cant-an-aws-lambda-function-inside-a-public-subnet-in-a-vpc-connect-to-the#:%7E:text=The%20reason%20that%20your%20Lambda,you%20have%20a%20public%20IP.)

To enable Internet access, you will need to [configure NAT Gateways or Instances](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)

Comment: This worked like a charm! I configured a NAT Instance with a public and private subnet following the instructions in the linked resources.