# Can we use both DynamoDb and VPC to an aws lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-vpc, amazon-elasticache

I am working on a AWS lambda in which i want to use DynamoDB and a VPC(Amazon elasticcache for redis). But I was getting time out error when trigger lambda

Comment: [You can use this as reference if you use the NAT Gateway option from Mark B's answer](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)

Comment: Can you provide the error that you were getting?

Comment: @AllanChua 
I am not getting any error simply my lambda is getting 30 seconds timeout. And I don't want to increase my lambda time >30 because We have a 30 seconds limit in API gateway

Comment: @samirkrishnacholleti, can you share what are you trying to achieve in the lambda? which language of the SDK did you use? Are you using transactions?

Answer (score 4):

You either need to create a [DyanmoDB VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/vpc-endpoints-dynamodb.html) in the VPC, or add a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) to the VPC, and only deploy the Lambda function in subnets that have a route to the NAT Gateway.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the VPC configuration subnet/Security Group of your lambda,

If your lambda is in a private subnet :

- If you want a secure internal way, you can pass with VPC endpoint
- Else if you want to pass with internet, you must have a NAT Gateway.

Check also the security groups/NACLS....

Comment: This is not correct for public subnets. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52994841/17896613)

Comment: Thank you @KaustubhKhavnekar, I didn't know the lambda don't have a public ip, I don't understund why ?  but I will change my answer based on that, that means when you deploy a default lambda (without vpc config) they deploy it in a private subnet + NAT ?

Comment: That is an internal AWS implementation detail, so unless AWS has publicly disclosed it somewhere, we won't know.

Comment: perfect ! Thank you