# Lambda triggered by a custom resource works without a VPC but inside the VPC the lambda gets Timeout

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have created a lambda that has to be triggered by a custom resource. Now when I test the lambda without putting it inside a VPC it works fine but whenever I put it inside a VPC the lambda does a timeout and the response is not sent back to the custom resource and the custom resource stack gets stuck on create in progress.

PS  Although when I put the lambda inside a VPC i put it inside public subnets.

Need help

I have created a lambda that has to be triggered by a custom resource. Now when I test the lambda without puttuing it inside a VPC it works fine but whenever I put it inside a VPC the lambda does a timeout and the response is not sent back to the custom resource and the custom resource stack gets stuck on create in progress.

PS  Although when I put the lambda inside a VPC i put it inside public subnets.

Comment: See [Why can't an AWS lambda function inside a public subnet in a VPC connect to the internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992085)

Comment: Does the function access resources on the Internet? If so, the problem is that it cannot reach the Internet. Is there a particular reason why you want to attach the Lambda function to a VPC? If it is NOT attached, then it will be able to access the Internet. If it IS attached, then you'll need to attach it to a **private subnet** and create a NAT Gateway to give it access to the Internet.

Comment: Thank You, it helped, the problem was solved