# AWS Lambda Async Invocation Issue: Function getting timed out intermittently when invoking another Lambda asynchronously

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am attempting to invoke an AWS lambda function asynchronously within another Lambda function using the boto3 SDK. The invocation is done using the following code snippet:

```
lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')
response = lambda_client.invoke(
    FunctionName='async_function:alias', InvocationType="Event",
    Payload=json.dumps({'id': '101932092', 'type': 'type', 'sub_type': 'subtype'})
)
```

The issues I am encountering is that the invoking function sometimes times out(15 minutes) at the above code block. The behavior occurs intermittently and there are no clear patterns.

I have ruled out concurrency and throttling issues on the invoked function by checking the relevant metrics. However, even though the invoke call is supposed to put the event in an event queue for asynchronous processing (as per [AWS Lambda documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html)), the invoking function times out without providing a success or error response.

Any insights or suggestions for trouble shooting this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the Lambda is configured for VPC access then you may have accidentally configured it with both private and public subnets. It should be private subnets only.

Comment: yes, it was configured with both public and private subnets. I have removed the public subnets, and I am currently monitoring its behaviour. I appreciate your suggestion! However, I am curious about the behaviour -  if the configurations were incorrect shouldn't it have never worked in the first place?. I had like to understand the underlying mechanism or any relevant resources you can point me to for a better explanation. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely reason for this intermittent connectivity is that your Lambda function has been configured for VPC access and you have chosen a mix of private and public subnets.

The fix is to configure the Lambda function for private subnets only or, if your Lambda functions only need to reach AWS services, then configure VPC Endpoints for the AWS services that you need access to.

The reason that the Lambda function fails intermittently is that it runs in a private subnet sometimes and in a public subnet at other times, depending on placement decisions made by the Lambda service. When the Lambda function executes in a public subnet, it has no network route to the internet or to AWS services. The reasons for this are:

1. the Lambda function has a private IP but does not have a public IP
2. the default route for traffic in a public subnet is the Internet Gateway, which drops traffic from private IPs (because they're not routable on the internet)
3. the default route for traffic in a private subnet, if you set it up correctly to reach the internet, is a NAT or NAT gateway which allows private IP traffic to be NATed to a public IP (the public IP of the NAT device) and hence that traffic can reach the internet

Also, see [Why can't an AWS lambda function inside a public subnet in a VPC connect to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992085/why-cant-an-aws-lambda-function-inside-a-public-subnet-in-a-vpc-connect-to-the)?

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful.