# Lambda hangs while uploading to S3, while uploading from a local server works just fine

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

The lambda is in a public subnet, but the S3 bucket is public regardless.

The lambda has the FullS3Access IAM role, and I tried making an endpoint for S3 in my VPC, to no avail.

The bucket's only custom permission is a single statement that allows everyone to get objects from it.

This is the piece of code where it hangs:

```
s3 = boto3.client(
        "s3",
        region_name=variables.secrets.AWS_REGION_NAME,
        aws_access_key_id=variables.secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key=variables.secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    )
    logger.debug("Connected to boto client")

    bucket_name = "user-images"
    file_name = f"public_{uuid4()}.{image.filename.split('.')[-1]}"

    try:
        logger.debug("Uploading file to s3...")
        s3.upload_fileobj(
            image.file,
            bucket_name,
            file_name,
            ExtraArgs={
                "ContentType": image.content_type,
            },
        )
        logger.debug("File uploaded to s3")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(str(e))
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            detail=str(e),
        )
```

The last debug statement that I get is "Uploading file to S3..." after which it hangs indefinitely.

The file is 60 kb so it shouldn't be a bandwidth or hardware related issue.

And perhaps most importantly, running the server on localhost uploads fine to S3 without any issues.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is it possible that the deployed lambda does not have the same permissions as your local dev environment?  IE, permission to list and write the bucket?

Comment: @MattMorgan The lambda has the "AmazonS3FullAccess" role, which as I understand it should grant all S3 related permissions.

Comment: How is `variables` populated?  Is it from the environment variables, or somewhere else?  Is the Lambda in the same region as the target bucket?

Comment: @AnonCoward Yes `variables` is populated from environment variables during the initialization of the lambda. I tried deleting the parameters (region_name, etc.) altogether to see if I'd get an error, but it still just hangs. Uploading from localhost without parameters still works. 
And yes they're in the same region.

Comment: You should not need to populate `aws_access_key_id` or `aws_secret_access_key`.  If you're using the permissions from the lambda role, that is not enough information.  You should let the AWS SDK pull in the credentials on it's own, since it needs to also deal with the credential rotation.

Comment: Why is the Lambda function in VPC? If it doesn't need to be, then don't. If it does need to be, because it accesses some other private resource in the VPC, then put it in a private subnet (not a public subnet). If it's in VPC, then it will also need either an S3 VPC Endpoint or NAT/IGW.

Comment: @AnonCoward Okay, but removing those still results in the same problem.

Comment: @jarmod It's in a public subnet of a VPC, it needs access to a database in a private subnet. It has an Internet gateway and I made an S3 VPC Endpoint, but no luck. 
As to it being in a public subnet, I thought that was the way to go for API Lambdas, thought maybe with an API gateway it doesn't need to be public? I'm new to this

Comment: There's rarely a good reason to put a Lambda function in a public subnet. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992085/why-cant-an-aws-lambda-function-inside-a-public-subnet-in-a-vpc-connect-to-the/52994841#52994841).

Comment: @jarmod Oh I did not know that's how that worked! Thank you, will try tomorrow at work. 
Btw if it solves the issue, how do I mark your answer as correct? I see no such button on comments.

Comment: Added an answer. Hope it helps. If you're using a VPC Endpoint for S3 and it's not working then you might want to create a new question specifically for that with details of what kind of S3 endpoint it is (gateway or interface), and what the endpoint policy looks like.

Comment: I think you left out the important part of your code.  Is this code actually called *while  processing the lambda request*?

Comment: @MattTimmermans Sorry, it's in a FastAPI router, so it gets called on a POST request on /images. The variables are ensured to be initialized before the request, during the setup of the main app, if that's why you're asking.

Comment: @jarmod Okay, appreciate it, will do if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Lambda function does not strictly need access to private resources in the VPC then don't configure it for VPC. That way you have an automatic route to the internet and AWS service endpoints (this is actually done by the AWS Lambda service, because your Lambda function is technically running on a compute instance within a Lambda service VPC and that service VPC has routing and NAT built in).

If your Lambda function does actually need access to private resources in the VPC, e.g. an RDS database or Elasticsearch cluster, then configure your Lambda function for VPC and place it in private subnet(s). Note that HA best practice is multiple private subnets, spanning multiple AZs for availability. Do not use public subnets - your Lambda function has no public IP so any traffic from it towards a public endpoint will be dropped at the IGW.

If your Lambda function needs to access AWS service endpoints then you can do that via VPC Endpoints, or via a subnet route to a NAT device (or NAT Gateway) in a public subnet of your VPC (which must have IGW, of course).

Comment: This worked! Feels counter intuitive, but I guess it's the way it is.

Comment: Related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52992085/why-cant-an-aws-lambda-function-inside-a-public-subnet-in-a-vpc-connect-to-the/52994841#52994841), with a little more info, for reference.